# Samsung Galaxy Grand Running Slowly After Upgrading to Android 4.2.2

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean, performance, samsung-galaxy-grand

I am using a *Samsung Galaxy Grand* for 8 months now, which was originally running Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean. Recently I got a Firmware Update and upgraded my mobile to Android 4.2.2. After this update, my mobile is running slow, and even RAM usage is too high.

Please help me how to solve this Issue.

Comment: It's worth noting that, in Android, high RAM usage is generally not a bad sign. However, the slowness you're experiencing **is** a real issue. Could you tell us more about the update method you used? Was it an OTA update? Did you do a factory reset before or after the update?

Comment: Thanks @dotVezz . I did Firmware Update Through OTA and i didn't do any Factory Reset before or After the Update

Comment: I'm thinking a factory reset could do the trick for you. Make sure do backup your things with something like Titanium Backup, then let us know how things go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking a factory reset could do the trick for you. Make sure do backup your things with something like Titanium Backup.

Answer (score 0):

guys just try factory reset i was having the same problem but now its smooth as earlier....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Samsung for fixing the issues and bugs in 4.2.2
They released a new update just a few days before and now it seems everything fine. No hanging after the latest stability update. Battery backup is fine. Charging time is reduced. Good performance. The only problem is I can’t download Facebook application because it gets stopped downloading after 60 or 70 %. But I can install the app using a backup. Now I am enjoying the new jellybean 4.2.2 after a few days regretting about updating my device.